# Angular Datatable ColVisibility Plugin

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I used angular-datatables for table, and its With ColVis Plugin (https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withColVis) for show/hide columns now I want to call services to maintain the column preference userwise (store column visibility state in database) so I had customized html open on click of show/hide column, I had took one button Update on click of this button I want to call web-service and after I will get response I will change the visibility of columns

But I am not able to bind the directive on update button click, once I able to bind directive I can call web service.

Can Anyone suggest whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your service on this state change event:

```html
angular.module('showcase.withColVis', ['datatables', 'datatables.colvis'])
.controller('WithColVisCtrl', WithColVisCtrl);

function WithColVisCtrl(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('data.json')
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
        // Active ColVis plugin
        .withColVis()
        // Add a state change function
        .withColVisStateChange(stateChange)
        // Exclude the last column from the list
        .withColVisOption('aiExclude', [2]);
    vm.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle('First name'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name')
    ];

    function stateChange(iColumn, bVisible) {
        console.log('The column', iColumn, ' has changed its status to', bVisible);
    }
}
```